# Share content to an company page on linkedin using api v2

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to publish some content in a company page on Linkedin using api v2. Reading the docs I've found two ways to share content, using ugcPosts and shares API. I successfuly shared content on a USER page using the ugcPosts. But, I cannot share a content in a COMPANY page using the ugcPosts. It looks like that using shares API I can share content in a company page. But the same [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api) says that SharesAPI will be deprecated soon.

I have two questions. First, there is a way to post content to a company page using ugcPosts? If not, it is safe to use the shares API since it will deprecated soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply for the linkedin partner program to get the manage pages permissions.

https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

Comment: But if I apply for this partner program I will be able to share content to a company page using ugcPosts?

Comment: Yes you will be able to share the  contents to company pages.

Comment: Can you share the code to post to linkedin Organization Pages ? Do we need to have specific scope to run this api ? I am getting the following error when I am calling the V2 api to get list of all organization where user is admin      
  {
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-roleAssignee /organizationalEntityAcls",
    "status": 403
}                                                                                                                                      I have already got the Marketing Developer approval for my Organization Page.

Comment: @Pawanlakhera add rw_organization_admin scope it worked for me.